# Can I run two application within the same app service?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a nodejs app and a .net core application. Is it possible to run both on the same app service using containers perhaps? If so would this go against best practices?

Edit:
Question is in regard to linux plan not windows

Comment: You can, without containers, by using IIS Application Scopes on the Configuration blade.

Comment: You could have two app services in the same app service plan as well.
You could also [create a multi-container (preview) app using a Docker Compose configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container)

Comment: Are you talking about having multiple Web App services on the same Linux App Service Plan or having multiple web applications on the same Web App service?

Comment: @Thomas Do you know if it is it cheaper to move both app services into one plan vs two plans & two services?

Comment: @lightbulb111 you pay for the app service plan not for the app service. Keep in mind that the two app services will share the same plan (=ram/cpu etc) so depends on the load  on the site you may want to have dedicated plan for each application